# How does `this` work in default parameters?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, default-parameters

So... ES6¹ (which happens to be standardized a few hours ago) brings *default parameters* for functions similar to those in PHP, Python etc. I can do stuff like:

```
function foo (bar = 'dum') {
    return bar;
}

foo(1); // 1
foo(); // 'dum'
foo(undefined); // 'dum'
```

MDN says that the default value for the parameter is evaluated at call time. Which means each time I call the function, the expression `'dum'` is evaluated again (unless the implementation does some weird optimizations which we don't care about).

My question is, how does `this` play into this?

```
let x = {
  foo (bar = this.foo) {
    return bar;
  }
}

let y = {
  z: x.foo
}

x.foo() === y.z(); // what?
```

The babel transpiler currently evaluates² it as `false`, but I don't get it. If they are really evaluated at call time, what about this:

```
let x = 'x from global';

function bar (thing = x) {
  return thing;
}

function foo () {
  let x = 'x from foo';
  return bar();
}

bar() === foo(); // what?
```

The babel transpiler currently evaluates³ it as `true`, but I don't get it. Why does `bar` not take the `x` from `foo` when called inside `foo`?

<sub>1 - Yes I know it is ES2015.

2 - [Example A](https://babeljs.io/repl/#?experimental=true&evaluate=true&loose=false&spec=true&playground=true&code=let%20x%20%3D%20%7B%0A%20%20foo%20(bar%20%3D%20this.foo)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20return%20bar%3B%0A%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A%0Alet%20y%20%3D%20%7B%0A%20%20z%3A%20x.foo%0A%7D%0A%0Aconsole.log(x.foo()%20%3D%3D%3D%20y.z()))

3 - [Example B](https://babeljs.io/repl/#?experimental=true&evaluate=true&loose=false&spec=true&playground=true&code=let%20x%20%3D%20'x%20from%20global'%3B%0A%0Afunction%20bar%20(thing%20%3D%20x)%20%7B%0A%20%20return%20thing%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Afunction%20foo%20()%20%7B%0A%20%20let%20x%20%3D%20'x%20from%20foo'%3B%0A%20%20return%20bar()%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Aconsole.log(bar()%20%3D%3D%3D%20foo())%3B)</sub>

Comment: Is there an announcement on the board's acceptance of the final ES6 draft?

Comment: @squint the spec is live at http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html :)

Comment: Your comparison essentially evaluates to `x.foo === y.foo` which is clearly `false`, because in both cases you are calling the `foo` function, but in the first case, `this === x` and in the second case, `this === y`. The question seems to really be, why is essentially `let x = {foo(){ return this; }}; let y = {z: x.foo}; y.foo() === y`. The answer is because `y.foo()` is the same as doing `y.foo.call(y)`. That is how `this` is defined.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> My question is, how does `this` play into this? I don't get it. Are they are really evaluated at call time?

Yes, the parameter initializers are evaluated at call time. [It's complicated](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-ecmascript-function-objects-call-thisargument-argumentslist), but the steps are basically as follows:

1. A [new execution context](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-prepareforordinarycall) is established on the stack,
   with a [new environment](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-newfunctionenvironment) in the "closure scope" of the called function
2. If necessary, it's [`thisBinding` is initialised](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-ordinarycallbindthis)
3. [Declarations are instantiated](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-functiondeclarationinstantiation):

   1. Mutable bindings for the parameter names are created
   2. If necessary, an `arguments` object is created an bound
   3. The [bindings are iteratively initialised](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-function-definitions-runtime-semantics-iteratorbindinginitialization) from the arguments list (including all destructurings etc)
      In the course of this, [initialisers are evaluated](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-destructuring-binding-patterns-runtime-semantics-iteratorbindinginitialization)
   4. If any closures were involved, a new environment is inserted
   5. Mutable bindings for the variables declared in the function body are created (if not already done by parameter names) and initialised with `undefined`
   6. Bindings for `let` and `const` variables in the function body are created
   7. The bindings for functions (from function declarations in the body) are initialised with instantiated functions
4. Finally the [body of the function is evaluated](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-function-definitions-runtime-semantics-evaluatebody).

So parameter initialisers do have access to the `this` and the `arguments` of the call, to previously initialised other parameters, and everything that is in their "upper" lexical scope. They are not affected by the variables declared in the function body (though they are affected by all the other parameters, even if in their temporal dead zone).

> what about this:
>
> ```
> function bar (thing = x) {}
> {
>   let x = 'x from foo';
>   return bar();
> }
> ```
>
> I don't get it. Why does `bar` not take the `x` from `foo` when called
>   inside `foo`?

Because `x` is a local variable that `bar` does not have access to. We're so lucky that they are [not dynamically scoped](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scope_(computer_science)#Dynamic_scoping)! The parameter initialisers are not evaluated at the call site, but inside the called function's scope. In this case, the `x` identifier is resolved to the global `x` variable.

Comment: If anyone cares, we had further discussion about this in [chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17/conversation/continued-discussion-for-how-does-this-work-in-default-parameters) if you wanna read up :)

Answer (score 0):

When they say "evaluated at call time", I think they're referring to a *call-by-name* expression. Here's how babel outputs your third example:

```
'use strict';

var x = 'x from global';

function bar() {
  var thing = arguments[0] === undefined ? x : arguments[0];

  return thing;
}

function foo() {
  var x = 'x from foo';
  return bar();
}

bar() === foo(); // what?
```

Since `var x` is inherited within the lexical scope of `bar` from the global scope, that is the scope in which it is used.

Now, consider the following:

```
let i = 0;

function id() {
  return i++;
}

function bar (thing = id()) {
  return thing;
}

console.info(bar() === bar()); // false
```

Which transpiles to

```
"use strict";

var i = 0;

function id() {
  return i++;
}

function bar() {
  var thing = arguments[0] === undefined ? id() : arguments[0];

  return thing;
}

console.info(bar() === bar()); // false
```

Notice how here, `id` is called *inside* the function, rather than being cached and memoized at the time the function is *defined*, hence the call-by-name rather than call-by-value.

So the behavior *is* actually correct in your second example. There is no `y.foo` and since `this` is *dynamically scoped* in Javascript (i.e. it varies based on the receiver of a given function invocation), when `y.z()` looks for `this.foo`, it will look for it in `y`, so `y.z()` will return `undefined`, while `x.foo()` will just return the `foo` function itself.

If you *do* want to bind to the receiver you can bind `foo` to `x` when you assign it. Then it should work as expected.

Sorry if any of this is unclear; let me know in the comments and I'd be happy to clarify! :)

Comment: _"and since this is dynamically scoped in Javascript"_, this is what my question is. Using `this.something` should not be taken specially because `this.something` is not magical, only `this` is. I will add a cleared example to question to clarify this, thanks for the answer!