# how to modify properties of an nested object?

Tags: javascript, object, javascript-objects, indexed

I have the following nested object and I need to leave the "alias" property blank and the "group" property set to true for all "entries" and "exits".  I also need to delete the whole "parameters" object.
Would there be a way to do it all in one function? I've tried to apply the delete Object method but it doesn't work as it's an indexed object.

```
{
  "1": {
    "x": 114,
    "y": 135,
    "properties": {
      "id": 1,
      "entries": {
        "entry_0": {
          "id": 1,
          "alias": "do",
          "group": false
        }
      },
      "exits": {
        "exit_0": {
          "id": 1,
          "alias": "re",
          "group": false
        }
      },
      "parameters": {
        "parameter_0": {
          "id": 3,
          "group": false
        }
      },
      "order": 1
    }
  },
  "2": {
    "x": 700,
    "y": 104,
    "properties": {
      "id": 1
      "entries": {
        "entry_0": {
          "id": 1
          "alias": "do"
          "group": false
        }
      },
      "exits": {
        "exyt_0": {
          "id": 1
          "alias": "re"
          "group": false
        }
      },
      "parameters": {
        "parameter_0": {
          "id": 3
          "alias": "mi"
          "group": false
        }
      },
      "order": 2
    }
  }
}
```

the desired nested object would be the following

```
{
  "1": {
    "x": 114,
    "y": 135,
    "properties": {
      "id": 1,
      "entries": {
        "entry_0": {
          "id": 1,
          "alias": "",
          "group": true
        }
      },
      "exits": {
        "exit_0": {
          "id": 1,
          "alias": "",
          "group": true
        }
      },
      "order": 1
    }
  },
  "2": {
    "x": 700,
    "y": 104,
    "properties": {
      "id": 1
      "entries": {
        "entry_0": {
          "id": 1
          "alias": ""
          "group": true
        }
      },
      "exits": {
        "exyt_0": {
          "id": 1
          "alias": ""
          "group": true
        }
      },
      "order": 2
    }
  }
}
```

what I've tried is the following, managing to delete the "parameters" object but I can't access the "label" property of each "entry" and "exit

```
const nedtedObjectsValues = Object.values(nestedObjects);
for (object of nedtedObjectsValues) {
   delete object.properties.parameters;

}
```

if anyone can give me an idea of how to approach this function.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: @Bergi ? I've just edited my question

Comment: Looks like I've written the comment before you submitted the edit. Thanks!

Comment: The `delete`ion of the `parameters` should work like you've written it. Now how did you try accessing the `alias` and `group` labels?

Comment: not sure how to do it... with other Object.values()??

Comment: Yes, exactly. You need to loop through the entries and you need to loop through the exists. You can [use `Object.values`, or any other enumeration approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46693246/1048572).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In JavaScript, to reference numeric object properties, you need to use the square brackets syntax:

```js
object.1 // bad
object[1] // good
```

You can delete numeric property like this:

```js
delete object[1];
```

Comment: but since in this case I want to delete them in all the numbered objects I have made a for to execute the delete in each one of the objects and still it gives me an error. in the for I separate the objects but it doesn't delete the desired property in any of them... thank u for your info

Comment: Then you do something wrong. This is correct syntax: `delete myObject.foo.bar[3].baz`.

Comment: You're right, I was missing the intermediate object "properties", I already managed to delete the parameters object